# how pass multiline variable into twig template

Tags: php, templates, twig

I would like to ask how pass multiline(string with linebreaks) variable into twig template.

I'm filling string variable with cycle, I need it is with lineends.

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $popissouboru = $row['jmeno_souboru'];
    $smernice.= $popissouboru.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Then I pass this variable to twigtemplate (HTML) where affected line looks like this

```
<p class="w3-text-black">{{ smernice }}</p>
```

But final output ignores the lineends and everything is in one line ...

Any idea how to pass linebreaks / ends ?

Thank you

Jan

Comment: Do you want an actual visual representation in the browser or only formatted in the source code?

Comment: I need visual represntation in browser ... I allready find way btw - I create string with html tags  ---> $smernice.='<p>'.$popissouboru.'</p>'; and in template I used this {{ smernice|raw }}

Comment: Okay, don't forget you can always use the filter [nl2br](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html) to convert newlines to breaks

Comment: yeah this look ok as well, i give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this when I searched for a solution to the very same problem. I add this as note to myself and for future readers:

If the actual problem is to get line-breaks in HTML simple use [nl2br](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html)

```
{{ content | nl2br }}
```

or just generate the content in question with `<br>` or `<p>`-tags in the first place, as hinted by the OP.

If you just want to remove the newlines use `replace`:

```
{{ content | replace({"\n":""}) }}
```

If your content also includes Windows lines endings use:

```
{{ content|replace({"\n":'', "\r":''}) }}
```

or just use the [trim](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/trim.html) filter which internally uses the PHP trim function which will strip all sorts of whitespace from the beginning and end of a string:

```
{{ content |trim }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the for-each-loop inside your twig template, too.
If you want line breaks, you could create a table without borders and for each loop value you use one table row. This might be beyond your purpose, though. I'll try anyway. Maybe it helps:

```html
{% for user in users %} 

<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.user_id }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.user_name }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ user.user_type }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

{% endfor %}
```

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // automatically load pathes
require_once "utils/Database.class.php"; // include database configuration

// init twig
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('template/'); // determines template path

//creates twig object and instances
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    "debug" => "true",
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());

include "utils/injector.php"; //sql injection

/* ------- */

DatabaseLink::getInstance()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// fetch data from database
$stmt = DatabaseLink::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$userData = $stmt->fetchAll();

//template values
$templateName = "listUsers.twig";
$data = array(
    "users" => $userData
);

//display
echo $twig->render($templateName, $data);
```